# ant exec not taking in file pattern

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I am trying to run an `exec` task in ant.

I am doing

```
<exec executable="javac">
    <arg value="-d"/>
    <arg value="${build.src.dir}"/>
    <arg value="${src.dir}/**/*.java"/>
</exec>
```

it gives the error

```
 [exec] javac: file not found: /home/anoop/Workspace/kmeans-mpi/src/**/*.java
 [exec] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
 [exec] use -help for a list of possible options
 [exec] Result: 2
```

Howver when I do

```
% javac -d build src/**/*.java
```

it works, and all the classes are generated

NOTE:
I am aware of `<javac>` target which ant provides, but I am using `<exec>` since I eventually plan to use `mpijavac` instead of `javac`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running as follows:

```
<exec executable="sh">
   <arg value="-c" />
   <arg value="javac -d ${build.src.dir} ${src.dir}/**/*.java" />
</exec>
```

Comment: It almost worked, but not exactly as I wanted to be. This does not match the file patterns like it does from the shell.If there is a class at `${src.dir}/Main.java` , it class file is not generated and neither of the files which are at `${src.dir}/xyz/abc/Some.java`. It only takes the exact match.